# ¿Como subir una imagen al servidor sin que se cierre mi modal en C# mvc?

Tags: c#, jquery, html5, ajax, .net

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Tengo un modal que carga una imagen, pero al dar clic al boton ***subir*** la imagen me recarga la pagina y se cierra el modal.

Lo que quiero es que no se recargue la pagina y se mantenga abierto mi modal después de haberlo subido.

Además no quiero usar razor @`Html.BeginForm` si no simplemente con `<form></form>` y trabajarlo con ajax y jquery ya que mi aplicación esta trabajando con ello.

Este es mi código

```
<!-- modal para ver detalles de un proyecto -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalEmpleadoSerie" tabindex="1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h6 class="modal-title" id="modal_det_title">Nuevo Registro</h6>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body bg-white">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("SubirImagen", "Acceso", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    <!--<input type="file" name="file" /> <button type="submit">Subir archivo</button>-->

                    @*<form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">*@
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Nombre:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="nombreEmpleado" id="idNombreEmpleado" type="text" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>IdExterno:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="IdExterno" id="idExterno" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>N° Serie:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nroSerie" id="idNroSerie" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Cargar Imagen</label>
                                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" id="idArchivoImagen" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>&nbsp;</label>
                                <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success" name="file" id="idSubir" value="Subir">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success" id="btnCrearErogacion">Guardar</button>
                    </div>
                    @*</form>*@
                }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Método C# mvc

```
public ActionResult SubirImagen(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            //Subir Imagen
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/");
            if (file != null)
            {
                string archivo = (DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + " - " + file.FileName).ToLower();

                file.SaveAs(path + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));

                return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Al button de subir sacarle el type="submit" y ponerle type="button" y luego con javascript o jquery capturar el click del boton de subir y enviar el ajax.

En el controller podrias devolver un JsonResult

Suerte